# file modified by opening

Tags: front-end

I am using MMA version 11.3.0. There are some notebooks that, right after being opened, change to modified. That is, their name in the title bar has an asterisk appended and, when I try to close it, it shows the "Save changes" dialog. As far as I can tell, there is no dynamic content.

Is there a way to prevent that behavior? I want to open a notebook and be able to close it immediately without having to save it.

Comment: It would be difficult to offer any suggestions without an example notebook.

Comment: does it have any dynamics in it? may be in view? may be this can be the cause? You can try to see at least.

Comment: I have been trying to generate a MWE but it seems random. I have copied parts of a "bad" notebook to a second notebook to see what triggers the behavior, but nothing so far.